# Reactjs performance working only after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple logic for when the value returns from the api, which is very simple if it returns from the api it shows a field filled in automatically, if it cannot release the field for the user to change the value, the problem is that when I do the first condition works better if I try to make the second condition remain enabled, and I only get the second conditional right after a page refresh, how can I solve this without reflashing?

```
   actualValue={`${
              constfat?.indicConsultaFat === "S"
                ? savedForm?.codigoOcorrencia?.valorFaturamento
                : savedForm.companyDataRevenue?.yearIncome || ""
   }`}

        disabled={constfat?.indicConsultaFat === "S" ? true : false}
```

Comment: My guess is that this is related to when you expect a render vs when a render actually happens. When you get your API response, are you calling a `state` setter, which would cause a render?

Comment: Yes, it has been yes, there are two states there, but I needed it to reset without needing to refresh the page I use or reactj in class

Comment: Can you upload a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise, you need to provide more information about the rest of your component.